# ReactJS Calling multiple Instances for Same Components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to call  Component twice from my App.js file but on rendering I am getting same instance of this component. This Component will get random image from Unsplash. Now I have come up with some solution like clearing the Instance first and call component again. How can we create new instance of this component by calling same component again?

Code: 
//Parallex.js

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './components/style/style.css';


class Parallex extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.para = this.para.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.para();
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this.isInViewport, true);
    }


    para() {
        $(document).ready(function(){

        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop()
        console.log("--------->" + scrolled);
        $('.parallax').each(function(index) {
            var imageSrc = $(this).data('image-src')
            var imageHeight = $(this).data('height')
            $(this).css('background-image','url(' + imageSrc + ')')
            $(this).css('height', imageHeight)
            var initY = $(this).offset().top
            var height = $(this).height()
            var diff = scrolled - initY
            var ratio = Math.round((diff / height) * 100)
            $(this).css('background-position','center ' + parseInt(-(ratio * 1.5)) + 'px')
        })

        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop()
          $('.parallax').each(function(index, element) {
            var initY = $(this).offset().top
            var height = $(this).height()
              var diff = scrolled - initY
              var ratio = Math.round((diff / height) * 100)
              $(this).css('background-position','center ' + parseInt(-(ratio * 1.5)) + 'px')
          })
        })
      })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref='UniqueElementIdentifies' className="parallax" id="parallax-2" data-image-src="**https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1081"** data-height="400px">
                <div className="caption">
                    <Button>Know more</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Parallex;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavbarComponent from './components/js/Navbar';
import Example from './carousal';
import Parallex from './parallex';
import FooteraboutUs from './footer-aboutus';
import {
  Jumbotron,
  Button,
 } from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';
import './Sticky-Navbar.css';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div>
          <Parallex/>
        </div>
      <div>
        <Example/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Parallex/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <FooteraboutUs/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when we are rendering components inside a loop, we give each component a key.
can you try giving your components a key? keys are supposed to give multiple copies of a component separated identities.

such like: `<Parallex key={1} />`

[KEYS](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: So I tried giving keys while calling Component but still getting same Instance of the Component. I think keys just let the dom know about the items changed

Comment: What if you get your image inside `componentDidMount()` pass to your state `this.setState({ imgSrc: https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1081 });`, this, will give enough time between the both of your component copies renders to get the image, basically what happens is when you import the function, it will be imported once, and that what you solved by clearing the component instance, if we say that there is 50ms between `componentDidMount()` methods for your components when rendering the App component, this would be enough, theoretically.